# How to Delete files which are in sub directories

Tags: vb.net, file, delete-file

Basically I've got `My Main Folder` and inside it there are `Folders B, C, D, E`. When I open my program, There is a `listbox` which shows all the `.txt` files inside `folders B, C, D, E`.

I've also got a button called `Delete`. What I want to do is select an item from the Listbox and click the `Delete Button` which will delete the selected listbox item from the actually directory.

E.g. I have `TextFile1` and `TextFile2` and `Textfile3` in `Folders B, D, E`. Now these files are distributed across all these sub directories. In order to delete them I will need to actually get each of the files location and then delete.

But the problem is that my Listbox only shows the name of all the files in all those sub directories. Is there a way to, when listbox item is selected, the get the textfile location and then delete the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I managed to solve this problem. So by default I had a Listbox with all the file names and I added another listbox where it will show all the files location with name so:

Listbox1: Filename
Listbox2: C:\Filename.txt

Now whenever the user clicks on whichever Listbox1 item, the selected index will be set to Listbox2. By doing this it's selecting the whole item with the path name and so that way I managed to set the code to delete through Listbox2.selectedItem

Comment: You can accept your own answer. In this way the problem is recorded as solved on SO.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Listbox Items as (Key,Value).
So, when you are adding file name to listbox add New item with

```
         Key: to show user
         Value : which has full path of file, can be used to delete it.
```

Something Like :

```
        lstTest.Items.Add(new ListItem("TestOneFile.txt", "c:\\A\\TestOneFile.txt"))
```

and the one delete get he value of selected item to use in delete command as;

```
        lstTest.SelectedValue.ToString()
```

Hope this will help you...!!

Answer (score 0):

i think what you should need is to save the path of your files in your database.
for example if txtfile is located in folder b you could save a path in you table e.g. c:\mainfolder\b. then if you want to delete the file, search the path of each file in your table to locate it then do a delete.

Comment: I can see where that is going and yes it's helpful but do you have any other alternative method?

Comment: I don't think there could be another method otherwise if the path of you file is constant, saving the path of each file will be the best solution.